# How to position landscape large figure?

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert a figure using the below commands:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \includegraphics[scale=0.5,angle=90]{fig.jpeg}
\caption{figure}
\end{figure}
```

But the figure is too big so it's shifted down on the page, and it's covering the page numbering as seen below:

[image]

I want it to be centered in the page, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: you could use simply \vspace{-3cm} before the graphic to move it up. But don't use `[!h]` as figure option, better remove it, or at least don't leave out the p to give LaTeX the chance to place it also on a float page.

Comment: Another possibility is to overlap the margins, using `\raisebox` for example.  You still need [p].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this solution work for you?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this works! but it shrinks the image a bit, is there a way to keep the original size/enlarge it?

Comment: Well, you wanted the image to fit on the page.. But sure, you could use ``scale=0.5`` as you did in your code, or you could adjust the width in my code, for example like ``width=1.1\textwidth``. I don't have your image file and don't know your paper dimensions, so I can't try what size would fit.

Comment: that works! thank you